# Morphism agree on generic point

Tags: schemes, topological-groups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be scheme.
Let $f$ and $g$ be morphism of scheme from $X$ to $Y$.
If $f,g$ agree on generic point of $X$, then $f$ and $g$ is the same map on $X$.

Does this hold in general ?

By famous statement of general topology,
if $Y$ is Hausdorff, the statement holds.But in Zariski topology $Y$ is often note Hausdorff, so I'm confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, “agree on the generic point”? Do you mean topologically or as morphisms of schemes starting of the spectrum of that local ring?

Comment: $f,g$ agree on means here ,same as  morphisms of schemes.

Answer (score 1):

There are, broadly speaking, two ways for the statement to be wrong. The first one, as in the topological case, is the possibility that $Y$ isn’t separated. In this case, you can consider the two natural injections from $\mathbb{A}^1$ into the “line with two origins”.

The second one, perhaps more subtle, is the possibility that the generic point doesn’t contain all the information about the functions on $X$, and it happens if $X$ is *not reduced*.

For instance, let $A=k[[t]][u]$ ($k$ field) with $tu=u^2=0$. Consider the two distinct ring maps $A \rightarrow A$ given by the identity and $t \longmapsto t,\,u \longmapsto 0$. Their scheme-theoretic counterparts are the same on the generic point but not equal.

Comment: What is the generic point of Spec$A$?0? You mean, your two map are equal on 0, but not equal on $SpecA$, right ?

Comment: The generic point of the spectrum of $A$ is the ideal $(u)$. The corresponding ring of stalks is $\mathbb{C}[[t]][t^{-1}]$ (ie $u$ is mapped to $0$) and the two maps have the same image in this localization.

Comment: Is this possible that give some extra condition? For example $Y$ is a variety

Comment: The usual condition is “$X$ reduced and $Y$ separated” (the latter may be replaced with “$Y$ is separated over some base scheme $S$ such that $f,g$ are $S$-morphisms). It’s a common enough condition in practice, but it’s not automatic.